# Microsoft-Cognitive add new person with chinese name

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using Face API now.The problem is about " add new person with chinese name ".

What should I do so that I can add person with chinese name ? Now I only get "?" when I try to create person with my android project. However I could add a chinese name when I using the api in web ?

Comment: By the way, i am using projectoxford project 1.4 version library.
`CreatePersonResult PersonResult = faceServiceClient.createPerson(
                        this.mPersonGroupId,
                        newPersonName,
                        null);`

Comment: What you're describing is a bug in the Android Client SDK library.  I've proposed a [fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/pull/33).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!
But how could I update my library ?
Any website to download the new version library?

Comment: There should be a 1.4.2 on Maven.  Can you give that a try?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I import it in my project.
How ever , I got  'java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]' exception when I use faceServiceClient.identity . And got java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8] when I use faceServiceClient.createPerson.